# Eclipse Tomcat Server starting but code is not getting deployed

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

The server status is showing as Started and Synchronized.

I am using Eclipse Kepler with Tomcat v7.0/
It is giving the following console output.

```
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 26, 2015 10:52:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Feb 26, 2015 10:52:45 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
WARNING: Failed to scan JAR [file:/C:/Users/gsharma1/Workspaces/Ride/OAS1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/onboardingapiserv-service/WEB-INF/lib/MonolithVO-interface-3.121.15353098.jar] from WEB-INF/lib
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:153)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:90)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:109)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.FileUrlJar.<init>(FileUrlJar.java:41)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:34)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig$FragmentJarScannerCallback.scan(ContextConfig.java:2680)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:259)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1947)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1261)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Feb 26, 2015 10:52:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processServletContainerInitializers
SEVERE: Failed to process JAR found at URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/gsharma1/Workspaces/Ride/OAS1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/onboardingapiserv-service/WEB-INF/lib/MonolithVO-interface-3.121.15353098.jar!/] for ServletContainerInitializers for context with name []
Feb 26, 2015 10:52:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
Feb 26, 2015 10:52:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
WARNING: Failed to process JAR [jar:file:/C:/Users/gsharma1/Workspaces/Ride/OAS1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/onboardingapiserv-service/WEB-INF/lib/MonolithVO-interface-3.121.15353098.jar!/] for TLD files
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:153)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:90)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:109)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.FileUrlJar.<init>(FileUrlJar.java:41)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:34)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanJar(TldConfig.java:489)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.access$100(TldConfig.java:59)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig$TldJarScannerCallback.scan(TldConfig.java:305)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:259)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.execute(TldConfig.java:278)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.lifecycleEvent(TldConfig.java:569)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Feb 26, 2015 10:52:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Feb 26, 2015 10:52:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Feb 26, 2015 10:52:46 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Feb 26, 2015 10:52:46 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Feb 26, 2015 10:52:46 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
Feb 26, 2015 10:52:47 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8083"]
Feb 26, 2015 10:52:47 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 26, 2015 10:52:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2540 ms
```

I have tried making a new workspace and trying again but of no use. Please tell what am i missing here?

Comment: either your jar is corrupted or compiled in other version. and also might be you have put zip file inside lib folder.

Comment: jar is working for my other teammates for same code. It has to be my workspace issue, right! any more pointers @Prashant ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

--> First Check that the file exists.

--> Try to open the file(Jar) in ZIP tool (WinZip, ...).

-->  verify the size of file with correct file; compare it to a "known good" copy.

--> replace the file from working server. and restart the server.

--> also check your disk space and folder permission.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same "Failed to scan JAR" message with a maven managed jstl jar file.

The solution was to :

1. Right click the project in Eclipse
2. Properties -> Targeted Runtimes
3. Tick Apache Tomcat

We knew it had to be Eclipse because the war file worked in a standalone Tomcat instance.